# how do you get 'screen-line' line numbers in vim?

Tags: vim

I know that in VIM you can do :set number, but still if a line wraps then it counts as <s>two</s> one line. What vim called linewise.

I can go up and down in a 'screen line' manner with `gj` and `gk`, so even if a line wraps onto multiple lines on screen, it'd go up and down a line at a time on the screen, but if I wanted to ever e.g. delete the next 30 lines in a screen-linewise sense, it'd be good to have screen-linewise numbers.

Is that possible / How can I do that?

Comment: "...in VIM... if a line wraps then it counts as 2 lines" A line wrapped due to terminal width will not count as 2 lines for linewise operators, it will count as 1, thus `j` will move 2 lines up on your terminal, but only 1 line up in vim line number count.

Comment: @jeremysprofile that was a mistype, I have corrected that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Almost all Vim commands address physical lines, not soft-wrapped screen lines. That's why features like `'relativenumber'` also count physical lines. Your editing tasks shouldn't heavily rely on navigation with `gj` / `gk`. Try one of the following alternatives:

- Re-format the document to have shorter lines, if possible. You could even define `:autocmd`s to break / re-assemble lines on load / save if the format on disk cannot be changed.
- Use visual mode (together with `j` and/or `gj`) to iteratively select the area. As you directly see the affected area, this also should be pretty fast.

If you really want numbering based on screen lines, you could take the old [RelativeNumber plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#RLTVNMBR) that emulated the mentioned option via the *signs column*, and modify that plugin to display screen lines instead. It still will be a pretty crude experience, though.